# jVectorMap renders at the wrong size and there does not appear to be a way to change it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, jvectormap

I'm using jVectorMap to create a map inside of a div.

However, no matter what I do, the map takes up only a small portion of the div. It seems that it is due to `<svg style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">`

I have tried setting the size on the containing div, I've tried various css solutions, but it still doesn't allow me to resize. The background color resizes, but the SVG element simply does not.

How do I resize the SVG element with jVectorMap?

Here is my script:

```
<script>
$('#map').vectorMap({
 map: 'world_mill_en',
  regionsSelectable: 1,
  regionStyle: {
  initial: {
    fill: 'white',
    "fill-opacity": 1,
    stroke: 'none',
    "stroke-width": 0,
    "stroke-opacity": 1
  },
  hover: {
    "fill-opacity": 0.8
  },
  selected: {
    fill: 'blue'
  },
  selectedHover: {
  }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

the same issue happened to me, this is exactly as you say, because the container width and height are set to 100%, but then wrong evaluated to 100px.

I changed this in my custom css to:

```
.jvectormap-container  { 
    width: inherited;  
    height: inherited;  
}
```

and also changed the jquery-jvectormap.2.0.2.js starting at line 2315 to get the height of my container in the function updateSize().
Then, i set width and height of the container in px with javascript in the window.resize event.

You may experience also this issue when the map is initialized in a secondary hidden page, for example in a single page webapp, because the calculated width and height are not yet accessible.
Hope this helps.

Comment: @DiegoPamio: nice to see someone happy, so you are building a full-size map? maybe you would like the whole stuff...?

Comment: I'm building a webapp which has a map as a form of navigation to country listings.

Answer (score 0):

The SVG won't automatically resize unless it has a `viewBox` attribute.  You will need to add one.  Exactly what its values need to be will depend on the contents of the SVG.

Once you have added a `viewBox`, you will need to remove the `width` and `height` values (or set them to `"100%"` - which has the same effect).

You may also need to adjust the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute.  It controls the scaling behaviour.